# /authorize call keeps returning 200 not 302

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, dotnet-httpclient, okta

I am trying to implement the authentication work flow manually by calling /authorize and get back 302 with redirect_uri which will have the authorization code as query string in the Location http response header.

when I do this using an OpenIdConnect library I get 302 response with the code in the redirect url in the Location header.

When I make the call manually using the following code

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        };
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
              string url2 = 
                      "https://sample.oktapreview.com/oauth2/auspx13uvj6eHSM9c0h7/v1/authorize? 
                      "response_type=code&"+"client_id=0oarcfbl1dwEszi1343343&"+
                      "state=Uy1Sa1pNcXFsMVlscV9qQVFkTjdyRzJTaW1mSnpxxxxxxxxxxL&"+                              
                      "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fhome&"+
                      "scope=openid%20groups%20profile%20email&"+
                      "code_challenge=xDz_AAOV0Cggf560t4kqEdDXQW3slDFKy34Pp6XTYJQ&"+
                      "code_challenge_method=S256&"+
                      "nonce=Uy1Sa1pNcXFsMVlscV9qQVFkTjdyRzJTaW1mSnxxxxxxxx";
            HttpRequestMessage message2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url2);
            var response2 = client.SendAsync(message2);
            response2.Wait();
            var res = response2.Result;
        }
```

I keep getting 200 response and Location in the header is null.

How can I make this call return 302? Is this something to do with the identity provider or the way I am handling the code?

I want to do this in dotnet core

Comment: What's in the body of the `200 OK` response? Is it prompting for credentials?

Comment: empty response nothing in the body